# Using two-ings in the same phrase. Is it grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

My dad is texting me using abbreviations.

Comment: Your sentence is fine. Problems sometimes arising when two **ing** words (participles/gerunds) follow one another. To learn more, you can google **double participles** or look at previous questions such as this:  https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167739/is-it-correct-to-use-two-present-participles-sequentially.

Comment: It's OK. You may be thinking about the so-called doubl-_ing_ constraint, where with certain verbs, two gerund-participles cannot occur consecutively, as in *"They are starting quarrelling".

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is correct. **Using abbreviations** is just adding more information.